# Any way to avoid boxing/unboxing inside linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, boxing

I am trying to write a Linq expression which checks whether any element in the List of objects matches with the predicate.

```
 protected override void ValidateRulesBeforeDelete(List<object> deleteRecords)
 {
     base.ValidateRulesBeforeDelete(deleteRecords);
     var defaultProductStatus = GetDefaultProductStatus();
     if (deleteRecords.Any(x => x.Equals(defaultProductStatus.Id)))
     {
         throw new CustomException(PageResource.ProductStatusViewModel_CannotDeleteDefaultProduct);
     }
}

public class ProductStatusViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The above code is working fine. But, recently I read about boxing/unboxing in **CLR Via C#** and my doubt is, to apply above predicate will the compiler box integer to object for each element in the list??

I am 100% sure all the time the list contains **integers** boxed as **object**.

So is there any way I can re-write the above code to avoid boxing/unboxing if there are happening any?.

Comment: If you are 100% sure your list is integers then why are you passing a `List<object>`?

Comment: It's from the common base class or the generic base class.

Comment: where the type changes according to different classes.

Comment: Probably the base class is/should be generic?

Comment: Do all the different classes have an `ID` property?  If so, make sure they all implement an interface that has that property, restrict your generic class on that interface and have the List be of that interface type

Comment: @maccettura sometimes there are combinations of keys forms a **ID** property. That's why I am not able to bind them to a specific type.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa sounds like you need to rethink your application design.  Its very, very rare that you ever want to deal with `object`.  You need to design your application so that you are using real types as much as possible

Comment: @maccettura thanks, I will change the generic base class now and impose inheriting members to specify the type.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa Once you update your code you could post it on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some feedback

Comment: So the base class should be `class Base<T>` and the inheriting members `class Sub : Base<int>` for example. (Just so we are talking about the same "generic")

Comment: Currently base class accepts Model type now I will add one more type for Key attribute